# Redirect from Member/Register is not working

Tags: members, htaccess, registration

In order to prevent unwanted member registration I have set up a redirect from the member/register page using the following code in the .htaccess file:

`Redirect 301 /member/register http://sitexyz.com/`

This should be working but it is not and returns the following url and still displays the registration page.

```
http://sitexyz.com/?/member/register
```

Am I missing something in the redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
RewriteRule ^member/register$ http://sitexyz.com/ [R=301,NC,L]
```

and make sure to place it before any index.php rewrite rules in your root htaccess file.